# cocos2d this->getBoundingBox

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

In a pawn class that inherits from the cocos2d Sprite class, I used this->getBoundingBox() in it's update function. This caused an "Access violation at reading location" error. Then, I swapped "this" with "GAME::PLAYER", a variable in a namespace that references the player and it worked. Why does this->getBoundingBox() cause an error when GAME::PLAYER->getBoundingBox() works perfectly fine? Aren't they supposed to be the same thing? Just to note, "this->" works with any other function but getBoundingBox. Is it something I'm doing wrong? I'm not THAT good with C++

Here's pawn.h

```
#include <cocos2d.h>

#ifndef PLAYER_CONTROLLER


#define PLAYER_CONTROLLER GAME::PLAYER







class pawn : public cocos2d::Sprite {
public:

pawn();
~pawn();

static pawn* create();
static pawn* create(bool default_moving);

bool moving;
bool right;
int speed;

cocos2d::Rect getBounds();
void step();
void initOptions();
void update(float dt) override;
void move(cocos2d::Vec2 vec);
void moveX(int x);
void moveY(int y);
virtual bool touchBegan(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
virtual void touchEnded(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);

};

namespace GAME {
static pawn* PLAYER;
};



#endif
```

Here's pawn.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include <cocos2d.h>


pawn::pawn() {

}

pawn::~pawn() {

}

bool pawn::touchBegan(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event) {
    this->move(cocos2d::Vec2(5, 0));
    this->moving = false;
    return true;
}

void pawn::touchEnded(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event) {
    this->moving = true;
}

void pawn::step() {
    if (this->moving) {
        if (this->right) {
            this->move(cocos2d::Vec2(this->speed, 0));
        }
        else {
            this->move(cocos2d::Vec2(-this->speed, 0));
        }
        if (this->getPositionX() < 0) {
            this->right = true; 
            CCLOG("Going right V4");
        }
        else {
            if (this->getPositionX() + this->getContentSize().width > cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getWinSizeInPixels().width + cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin().x){
                this->right = false;
                CCLOG("Going left V4");
            }
        }
    }
}

void pawn::move(cocos2d::Vec2 vec) {
    PLAYER_CONTROLLER->setPosition(cocos2d::Vec2(PLAYER_CONTROLLER->getPositionX() + vec.x, PLAYER_CONTROLLER->getPositionY() + vec.y));
}

void pawn::moveX(int x) {

}

void pawn::moveY(int y) {

}

void pawn::update(float dt) {
    //cocos2d::Rect act = this->getBoundingBox();
    this->getPosition();
    this->step();
}

cocos2d::Rect pawn::getBounds() {
    if (!PLAYER_CONTROLLER) {
        CCLOG("Is this the problem?");
    }

    return PLAYER_CONTROLLER->getBoundingBox();
}

pawn* pawn::create() {

    auto character = new pawn();
    character->moving = true;
    character->right = false;
    character->speed = 5;
    character->setPositionY(50);

    if (PLAYER_CONTROLLER == NULL) {
        CCLOG("There is no player, yet.");
        CCLOG("Adding player");
        PLAYER_CONTROLLER = character;
    }
    else {
        CCLOG("There's already a player");
        return NULL;
    }

    //character->setPositionX(40);
    if (character->initWithFile("Base.jpg")){
        return character;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(character);
    return NULL;
}

pawn* pawn::create(bool default_moving) {

    pawn* character = new pawn();
    character->moving = default_moving;
    character->setPositionX(40);
    if (character->initWithFile("Base.jpg")){
        return character;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(character);
    return NULL;
}
```

Is it maybe because I call a pawn method from another class? I use a Collider class to call functions in pawn

Collider.cpp

```
#include "Collider.h"
#include "player.h"


Collider::Collider() : CollideMode(OVERLAP) {

}

Collider::~Collider() {

}

Collider* Collider::create() {
    Collider* col = new Collider;

    if (col->initWithFile("Base.jpg")){
        col->setAnchorPoint(cocos2d::Vec2(0, 0));
        col->setContentSize(cocos2d::Size(100, 100));
        return col;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(col);
    return NULL;
}

void Collider::collision(cocos2d::Vec2 intersect) {
    CCLOG("IT IS COLLIDING");
    if (intersect.x < intersect.y) {
        PLAYER_CONTROLLER->move(cocos2d::Vec2(-intersect.x, 0));
        CCLOG("X");
    }
    else if (intersect.x > intersect.y) {
        PLAYER_CONTROLLER->move(cocos2d::Vec2(0, -intersect.y));
        CCLOG("Y");
    }
}

void Collider::update(float dt) {
    //cocos2d::Rect col = this->getBoundingBox();
    auto act = PLAYER_CONTROLLER->getBounds();
    if (PLAYER_CONTROLLER) {
        if (!PLAYER_CONTROLLER) {
            CCLOG("There is no player?");
        }

    }
    else {
        CCLOG("Not colliding");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like `getBoundingBox()` is accessing null values somwhere  and thus you are crashing. Have you verified through the debugger that `getBoundingBox()` does not access null values? Also `this->` and `GAME::PLAYER` are not the same it sounds like. If I'm correct in understanding your post, your `Pawn` object is your pointer (this->) and the other is your player object (GAME::PLAYER), is that correct?

Comment: @TheRoomDiedWithIt please post your `pawn` class

Comment: I left my house, so I can't really post my pawn class yet , and why it took long to reply. Also, there's a create function in the pawn class, it makes a pawn object and sets GAME::PLAYER as that pawn object. Inside the update function of the pawn class, calling this->getBoundingBox results in an error. While GAME::PLAYER works perfectly fine. This is weird since in a pawn function in which I call this->getBoundingBox it doesn't work. Which is weird since I use GAME:: PLAYER-> to call the function in the first place.

Comment: Edit: Things have changed. I don't know what happened, but now it's even denying PLAYER_CONTROLLER or GAME::PLAYER ( they're the same, PLAYER_CONTROLLER is just a macro ). What's weird is that it's even accepting and denying PLAYER_CONTROLLER in the same function. I have no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seems any problem  with `this->getBoundingBox()` inside `update(float dt)` function.

I've created small test :

declaration inside `.h` file

```
class MySprite: public Sprite {

public:

    bool init() override;
    void update(float) override;

    CREATE_FUNC(MySprite);
};
```

Now method definition inside `.cpp` file

```
bool MySprite::init(){

    if(!Sprite::init())
        return false;

    scheduleUpdate();
    return true;
}

void MySprite::update(float dt){

    auto rect=this->getBoundingBox();
    CCLOG("Inside Update method of MySprite Bounding rect Width %f & Height %f",rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
}
```

Then I created an autoreleased object of `MySprite` and add to parent.

```
auto mysprite=MySprite::create();
mysprite->setContentSize(Size(10,10));
addChild(mysprite);
```

Run, Expected result on output console.

Answer (score 0):

I see my mistake. It was the fact that I redefined the namespace "GAME" and it's variable, "GAME::PLAYER" every time I included pawn.h, the other source files that I called the pawn functions from didn't know what GAME::PLAYER or PLAYER_CONTROLLER ( just a macro for GAME::PLAYER ) was, as I had only defined PLAYER_CONTROLLER in pawn.cpp. That's why when you called PLAYER_CONTROLLER->method() in another file, it passed in NULL as "this", and also why PLAYER_CONTROLLER was referring to a different PLAYER_CONTROLLER than the one passed in as "this".

I solved it by using the extern keyword that makes the variables global between all files, which was my original intention.

pawn.h

```
#include <cocos2d.h>

#ifndef PLAYER_CONTROLLER


#define PLAYER_CONTROLLER GAME::PLAYER
#define INITIALIZE_PLAYER pawn* GAME::PLAYER = NULL





class pawn : public cocos2d::Sprite {
public:

    pawn();
    ~pawn();


    static pawn* create();
    static pawn* getController();
    static pawn* create(bool default_moving);

    bool moving;
    bool right;
    int speed;

    cocos2d::Rect getBounds();
    void step();
    void initOptions();
    void update(float dt) override;
    void move(cocos2d::Vec2 vec);
    void moveX(int x);
    void moveY(int y);
    virtual bool touchBegan(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
    virtual void touchEnded(cocos2d::Touch*, cocos2d::Event*);
};




namespace GAME {
    extern pawn* PLAYER;
};



#endif
```

This is why I said I wasn't that good at C++.